# How to bind Maui MenuFlyoutItem command?

Tags: c#, maui-windows

Edit: Updated as recommended by Liqun Shen-MSFT.

I must be missing something really basic. I'm trying to get clicking on a MenuFlyoutItem to open a Popup using the Maui community toolkit. So starting from the default Maui app (and building for Windows machine), I've added the toolkit to the builder in MauiProgram.cs:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace GsnEdMaui;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

On my MainPage.xaml I've added a menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GsnEdMaui.MainPage"
         x:Name="this">
    <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="Settings"  BindingContext="{Binding Path=BindingContext,Source={x:Reference this}}">
            <MenuFlyoutItem  Text="Program" Command="{Binding SettingsProgramCommand}"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Project" Command="{Binding SettingsProjectCommand}"/>
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Image
            Source="dotnet_bot.png"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
            FontSize="18"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            Text="Click me"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And in the code behind I have defined the commands:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
```

namespace GsnEdMaui;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
int count = 0;

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = this;
}

private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;

    if (count == 1)
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
    else
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

    SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
}

private void ExitCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO ExitCommand
}

private void FileNewCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO FileNewCommand
}

private void FileOpenCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO FileOpenCommand
}

private void FileSaveCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO FileSaveCommand
}

private void SettingsProgramCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO SettingsProgramCommand
}

private Command SettingsProjectCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            this.ShowPopup(new SettingsProjectView());
        });
    }
}
```

}

I don't think I need to show the contents of the `SettingsProjectView` page, because if I set a breakpoint in `SettingsProjectCommand` I find it's not getting called when I click the  `Project` menu item. So what am I missing? Why does the command not go through?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That because the BindingContext not being passed on to the menuitems. You could maually set the BindingContext.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="this">

<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Settings"  BindingContext="{Binding Path=BindingContext,Source={x:Reference this}}">
        <MenuFlyoutItem  Text="Program" Command="{Binding SettingsProgramCommand}"/>
        ...
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Command bound with MenuFlyoutItem is not getting executed, whereas Clicked event is working fine #5382](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5382)

By the way, I haven't seen you set the BindingContext of MainPage.
You could simply set the BindingContext of the MainPage like the following:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this; // set the bindingContext to the page itself
    }

    // also change SettingsProgramCommand to type Command
    public Command SettingsProgramCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                //implement what you want to do here
                Console.WriteLine("12345");
            });
        }
    }
......
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/?view=net-maui-7.0) and [Use the command interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-7.0#use-the-command-interface). If you still have any question feel free to ask.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks - so I was missing things *and* there was an issue with Maui itself! I wouldn't have found that without your help! But I've updated the code as you suggest (I think) and the command is still not getting through. Question updated to reflect that.

Comment: Actually it's  ```public Command SettingsProgramCommand```. It's a public not private method.