# How to bind maui command parameter?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

**Visual Studio 2022 17.8.5, .NET8**

I have 2 pages.

The first view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="Items"
             x:Name="ThisItemsPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <material:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <material:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label ... />
                        <Label ... />
                        <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Details" 
                                                Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}"
                                                BindingContext="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference ThisItemsPage}}" 
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.BindingContext}" />
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                                                Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" 
                                                BindingContext="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference ThisItemsPage}}" 
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.BindingContext}" />
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </material:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </material:TreeView>
        <!-- other elements -->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Its cs class:

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    private ItemsViewModel Context;

    public ItemsPage(ItemsViewModel viewModel)
    {
    InitializeComponent();
        Context = viewModel;
        BindingContext = Context;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And ItemsViewModel:

```
public partial class ItemsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Item? _selectedItem;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Details(Item obj)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Delete(Item obj)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }

    // ...
}
```

The second view:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:SpendAdvisor.Models"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SpendAdvisor.Converters"
             x:Class="SpendAdvisor.Views.OtherItemsPage"
             x:Name="ThisOtherItemsPage"
             Title="OtherItems">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- other elements -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OtherItems}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Border>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="100, *, 80">
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" ... />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" ... />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" ... />

                                <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Details" 
                                                        Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}"
                                                        BindingContext="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference ThisOtherItemsPage}}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.BindingContext}" />
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"
                                                        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                                                        BindingContext="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference ThisOtherItemsPage}}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.BindingContext}" />
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <!-- other elements -->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Its cs class:

```
public partial class OtherItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    private OtherItemsViewModel Context;
    public OtherItemsPage(OtherItemsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Context = viewModel;
        BindingContext = Context;
    }
    // ...
}
```

And OtherItem view model:

```
public partial class OtherItemsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<OtherItem> _otherItems = new ();

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Details(OtherItem obj)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Delete(OtherItem obj)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }

    // ...
}
```

I got the next exception only with the second page (when I try to open it):

Parameter "parameter" (object) cannot be of type Myapp.ViewModels.OtherItemsViewModel, as the command type requires an argument of type Myapp.Models.OtherItem. (Parameter 'parameter')

If I change parameter `OtherItem obj` to `object obj`, everything works ok, and type of object is `OtherItem`. I can't understand it: it passes right object, but it expects that it shouldn't be that type. Looks like `CommandParameter` doesn't work at moment of page initialization, but works at runtime. But at the same time why it works with the first page.

So how to pass that parameter in right way? I can keep object parameter and call something like `var casted = obj as OtherItem`, but I want to have single style of commands.

Comment: try `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just removed `ViewCel` and replaced `ListView` with `CollectionView`. And everything works now as expected: `Details(OtherItem obj)` accepts `OtherItem` type without exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The exception makes sense when you think about it, what you are trying to do here is

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.BindingContext}"
```

In your command parameter, pass the binding context of the parent, but you see the BindingContext of your parent i.e. your ListView, is your ViewModel i.e. OtherItemsViewModel, instead what you should be doing is sending the current object as the parameter doing that is quite simple, you basically do this in a ListView/CollectionView's ItemTemplate

```
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
```

Feel free to revert with queries

Comment: If I keep `BindingContext` and use `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`, `OtherItemsViewModel` will be passed (but I wanted to get my `OtherItem` model). This is expected, as `BindingContext` references context of `ThisOtherItemsPage`, where `BindingContext` is view model.

If I remove `BindingContext` and set `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`, command is not triggered at all.

There is similar topic, where noticed that we should set binding context manually to menu items [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75934449/how-to-bind-maui-menuflyoutitem-command)

Comment: You can check my first view, there I have no problems although I use the same syntax to get parent context.

Comment: please review my answer, do you have any idea, why ListView is so complicated?